# Nuxtjs including images from assets using the content module

Tags: web, content-management-system, nuxt.js, blogs, nuxtjs

I am trying to use the nuxt.js [Nuxt.js content module](https://content.nuxtjs.org/). Is there a way to display images we refer to in our blogpost.md file? I know that we can put images in the front matter, but I want the create of the articles to put images inside their created .md file. Lets say we have a file:

-- start of .md file --

```
# some text

some description

![Image of test](../../assets/images/test.jpg)
![Image of Yaktocat](https://octodex.github.com/images/yaktocat.png)# some text

some description
```

-- end of .md file --

I end up seeing the image that is linked using https. But the other image is not displayed?? When checking the page I see an <img> tag is created, but no image to be seen...
When I check the structure using any other markdown editor, I see the image.

Including links to images does display images. But I need to include locally stored images.

any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Partially solving the issue, some images can be added using metadata (like cover images), those cannot be added within the content itself, just above or bellow actual content.

```
---
title: Sample
image: test.jpg
---

Here the markdown (without images)
```

In the view you can render that image after or before the content using something like:

```
<img :src="require(`~/assets/images/${ page.image }`)">
<nuxt-content :document="page"/>
```